# Why 1 + decrementing the value + 1 = 2?

Tags: php, operators

I found a piece of code (from one of our developer) and I was wondering why the output of this is 2?

```
<?php
  $a = 1;
  $a = $a-- +1;
  echo $a;
```

thanks

Comment: Can you please put the code in a reasonable way?

Comment: can I see the 2 lines above and below this line? :)

Comment: Can you show this piece of code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'll give my explanation a whirl. We're talking about a variable referencing some value off in the system.

So when you define `$a = 1`, you are pointing the variable `$a` to a value `1` that's off in memory somewhere.

With the second line, you are doing `$a = $a-- + 1` so you are *creating a new value* and setting that to `$a`. The `$a--` retrieves the value of the original `$a`, which is `1` and adds `1` to make `2` and creates that value somewhere else in memory. So now you have a variable `$a` which points to `2` and some other value `1` off in memory which along the way decremented to `0`, but nothing is pointing at it anymore, so who cares.

Then you echo `$a` which points to your value of `2`.

Edit: [Testing Page](http://dev.animuson.net/~stack-overflow/7788032~why-1-decrementing-the-value-1-2.php)

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, I got it now

Comment: is it me or it's kinda stupid to do so (I mean program that way) using $a-- + 1?

Comment: @Pat R Ellery: Not necessarily, if another variable has reference to that same location, then that variable would still point to the decremented value. In this specific instance, the `--` is useless.

Answer (score 20):

$a-- decrements the value after the line executes. To get an answer of 1, you would change it to --$a

```
<?php
 $a = 1;
 $a = --$a +1; // Decrement line
 echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: so if the $a-- decrements after the line, at the echo $a it will be $a = 2; then $a = 1 ($a--) then it echo $a which is 1 no?

Comment: @James: -1. `$a--` does not decrement the value after the line executes, it decrements it *before* the +1 occurs. However, the expression evaluates to the original value of `$a` before decrementing, which explains this behavior.

Comment: When doing a incremental decrease or increase. It will not set the increment if it is after the variable and it is setting itself (in an equation). To get it part of the equation (to decrement during), you add the increment portion prior to the variable.

Comment: @robjb I was just adding that in a comment at the same time. I relized after i had wrote it it made no sense.

Comment: Ok, I know in principle why this works, but after reading everyone explain it, I think it would be great if someone would actually dissect the actual line `$a = $a-- + 1` and explain what the php interpreter is actually doing ;)

Comment: @Ryan Look at the answer that Radu gave and the comment that robjb put. That is how it is disecting the equation.

Answer (score 12):

### What the?

Just to clarify the other answers, what you have going on in this line:

```
 $a = $a-- +1;
```

Basically when PHP evaluates $a--, it actually returns the value of $a, and then runs the operation of decrementing it.

### Try this

```
$a = 1;    
echo $a--; //outputs 1;
echo $a;  //outputs 0;
```

When you run this code, you will see that the number only decrements after it has been returned. So using this logic, it's a bit more clear why

```
echo $a-- + 1;
```

would output 2 instead of 1.

### A better way

Perhaps a better way, arguably more clear would be

```
$a = $a -1 + 1
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$a = 1; /* $a is 1 */
$a = ($a--) /* returns 1 and decrements the copy of $a */ + 1 /* 1 + 1 = 2 */;
echo $a; /* 2 */
```

The above is equivalent to something like:

```
$a = 1;         /* $a is 1 */
$temp = $a + 1; /* 1 ($a) + 1 = 2 */ 
$a = $a - 1;    /* decrements $a */
$a = $temp;     /* assigns the result of the above operation to $a */
echo $a;
```

That actually pretty much what PHP translates that into, behind the scenes. So `$a--` is not such a useful operation, since `$a` is going to be overwritten anyway. Better simply replace that with `$a - 1`, to make it both clearer and to eliminate the extra operation.

Comment: I think it would actually be `$temp = $a;`, then `$a = $a - 1;` and `$a = $temp + 1;`